# How to count number of messages a user sent from json output

Tags: python, json

Below is a sample JSON output I have of messages that users sent.  I want to count how many messages were sent by each user.  The issue is that each object starts with a unique string. (i.e. the first object starts with '-KWvQJDwln4eECyxtnF_')

The end result I'm looking for is:
user_id : number of messages sent by user

I want to have a name value pair containing the key and the user_id
Example: 
`-KWvQJDwln4eECyxtnF_ : 10 //10 is from user_id`

```
   [ null, {
  "-KWvQJDwln4eECyxtnF_" : {
    "blocked" : false,
    "consumedByPartner" : false,
    "dpid" : "example",
    "groupId" : 0,
    "id" : "-KWvQJDwln4eECyxtnF_",
    "likes" : 61,
    "messageType" : 0,
    "name" : "jon",
    "possibleAdultImage" : false,
    "possibleViolentImage" : false,
    "text" : "first message",
    "time" : 1479539507645,
    "userid" : 10
  },
  "-KWvQk3XmYa-nwQ54g6x" : {
    "blocked" : false,
    "consumedByPartner" : false,
    "dpid" : "example",
    "groupId" : 0,
    "id" : "-KWvQk3XmYa-nwQ54g6x",
    "imageUrl" : "example",
    "likes" : 60,
    "messageType" : 0,
    "name" : "jondotli",
    "possibleAdultImage" : false,
    "possibleViolentImage" : false,
    "text" : "",
    "time" : 1479539621666,
    "userid" : 8
  },
  "-KWvR6v45NvpO-kIhAne" : {
    "blocked" : false,
    "consumedByPartner" : true,
    "dpid" : "example",
    "groupId" : 0,
    "id" : "-KWvR6v45NvpO-kIhAne",
    "imageUrl" : "example",
    "likes" : 126,
    "messageType" : 1,
    "name" : "jondotli",
    "possibleAdultImage" : false,
    "possibleViolentImage" : false,
    "text" : "",
    "time" : 1479539719365,
    "userid" : 8
  }
  }]
```

Comment: The JSON is not even valid, but which language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I have corrected it.

I'm trying to parse it in Python.

Answer (score -1):

1. Your JSON is not valid. Put closing " at line 27 for "imageUrl": "example,
2. Save your JSON as JSON array, or if it's a string, convert it into jsonarray. Here, I have taken string fullline in which have stored your JSON. Solution to get user id is

   ```
   JSONArray rootObject = new JSONArray(fullline);

   for (int i = 0; i < rootObject.length(); i++) {

       if (rootObject.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
           JSONObject elements = rootObject.getJSONObject(i);
           Set<String> keys = elements.keySet();
           for (String k : keys) {
               JSONObject keyRow = elements.getJSONObject(k);

               Object userid = keyRow.get("userid");
               System.out.println(userid.toString());

           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: _Please accept the answer._ How can you assume the OP is using Java?

Comment: Logic is not language dependent. I have given him the logic.

Comment: It is a jsonArray - i'm trying to parse it in Python.